# Converting to an int in LINQ not working?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

The following query complains that the int conversion is not supported.

```
var list = from d in data
           where d.Id == (int)GridView1.DataKeys[0].Value
           select d;
```

It complains on the (int)GridView1.SelectedInex line telling me that the Int conversion is not supported.  I also tried Convert.ToInt32, but that did not work either.

Is this logic that has to be calculated before such as above the linq query or is there a special way to do it and if not, why does it not support it?

Comment: first..where is (int)GridView1.SelectedInex its not in the code example..also it should be d.Id ==

Comment: Are you getting a compile error or a runtime error? What exactly is the error message?

Comment: conversion not supported is a runtime error, caused because part of the query cannot be parsed by the provider (linq to sql provider in this case)

Comment: Thanks Sander, I got a compile error 'cannot implicity convert int to bool', and was unsure if it was that he was refering to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not try and parse the value to an integer before hand, it's not needed in the query.

```
Int id;
if (Int32.TryParse(ridView1.DataKeys[0].Value.ToString(), out id))
{
    var list = from d in data
               where d.Id == id
               select d;
}
```

Comment: = needs to be == otherwise the expression will fail as it is not boolean.

Comment: @envalid: fixed, sorry, copy paste oversight :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume the semicolon after the where line is a typo?

Pull the cast outside the linq query, it's trying to generate SQL for the cast operation, which isn't supported

```
int id = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[0].Value;
var list = from d in data
           where d.Id = id
           select d;
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, I removed the semi-colon.  This is what I meant about doing the logic above the query first and then using the calculated value in the where clause.

Comment: So what you are saying is that Linq does not support the SQL CAST expression? Do you know why?

Comment: it doesn't have to do with SQL CAST, the Linq provider translates the Linq query to SQL by parsing the expression tree. It can't do that when an operation in the tree cannot be translated to SQL

Comment: Shouldn't the CAST in the linq query generate a SQL cast that can be generated translated to SQL.

Comment: No, it cannot be mapped. .Cast<T> and .OfType<T> work though, but that's on IEnumerable/IQueryable

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but try:

```
where d.Id == (int)(GridView1.DataKeys[0].Value);
```

in case it's trying to cast the GridView.

(edit: fixed code - see comment on question)

**This answer is *wrong*!**

Comment: That's not the case, this code is equivalent to the code in the question

Comment: OK. No problem - just a guess! :)

Answer (score 0):

you are casting, not converting.

```
int.Parse( GridView1.DataKeys[0].Value )
```

would be converting.

GridView1.DataKeys[0].Value returns an object which may or may not be an int.

Comment: casting or not casting isn't what's causing that message